# Auto-sklearn: How to load pickle file and run predict()

Tags: python, automl

I have fitted a classification model using auto-sklearn, and managed to save it to a file with pickle.

```
x = automl.show_models()
results = {"ensemble": x}
pickle.dump(results, open('file.pickle','wb'))
```

I also have managed to reload the model.

```
automl = pickle.load(open('file.pickle','rb'))
```

But I can't manage to use the reloaded model to run predictions on new data.
When I run:

```
y_hat = automl.predict(X_test)
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

Comment: you can try MLJAR AutoML https://github.com/mljar/mljar-supervised - it automatically save and load models, no need to directly call load/save

Answer (score 6):

**Incorrect:**

```py
x = automl.show_models()
results = {"ensemble": x} # <---
pickle.dump(results, open('file.pickle','wb'))
```

**Correct:**

```py
x = automl.show_models()
#results = {"ensemble": x}
results = autml # the classifier/regressor itself
pickle.dump(results, open('file.pickle','wb'))
```

**Sample code for Iris:**

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from autosklearn.classification import AutoSklearnClassifier
import pickle


# dataset:
X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)

# train model:
classifier = AutoSklearnClassifier(
    time_left_for_this_task=30, 
    per_run_time_limit=60,
    memory_limit=1024*12) # depends on your computer
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# save model
with open('iris-classifier.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(classifier, f)

# load model
with open('iris-classifier.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    loaded_classifier = pickle.load(f)

# predict
y_true = y_test
y_pred = loaded_classifier.predict(X_test)
print('iris classifier: accuracy:', accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred))
# iris classifier: accuracy: 0.9333333333333333
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of dumping the output of `automl.show_models()`, I think you should dump the `automl` object instead, since this is the only class having the `predict` method.